# How to loop over multiple groups and create radar plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart, ggradar

I have the following dataframe:

| group | Class | Maths | Science |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 7 | 74 | 78 |
| Name2 | 7 | 80 | 91 |
| Name3 | 6 | 69 | 80 |

I want to create different radar plots for the variables Maths and Science for each classes using R. eg: For the above dataframe, two radar plots should be created for two classes 7 and 6.

```
nrange <- 2
class <- c(7,6)
for (i in nrange){
plot <- ggradar::ggradar(df[i,2:3], values.radar = c(0, 50, 100), group.line.width = 1,
               group.point.size = 2, legend.position = "bottom", plot.title=class[i])
}
plot
```

I using the above code. However, it is only creating the plot for the last row. Please help me with this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, but there were two little problems.

1. The for statement evaluated to `for(i in 2)` which means it is only using `i=2`.  You can fix this by using `for(i in 1:nrange)`
2. You were overwriting `plot` each time through the loop.  If you make `plot` a list and save each graph as a separate element in the list, then it should work.

```r
mydat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group,   ~Class, ~Maths, ~Science,
"Name1",    7,  74, 78,
"Name2",    7,  80, 91,
"Name3",    6,  69, 80)

plots <- list()
nrange <- 2
class <- c(7,6)
for (i in 1:3){
  plots[[i]] <- ggradar::ggradar(mydat[i,2:4], values.radar = c(0, 50, 100), 
                           grid.max = 100, group.line.width = 1,
                           group.point.size = 2, legend.position = "bottom", plot.title=mydat$Class[i])
}
plots
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

#### Putting Together with facet_wrap()

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mydat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group,   ~Class, ~Maths, ~Science,
  "Name1",    7,  74, 78,
  "Name2",    7,  80, 91,
  "Name3",    6,  69, 80)

mydat <- mydat %>% 
  mutate(gp = paste(group, Class, sep=": ")) %>% 
  select(gp, Maths, Science)

  ggradar::ggradar(mydat, values.radar = c(0, 50, 100), 
                                 grid.max = 100, group.line.width = 1,
                                 group.point.size = 2, legend.position = "bottom") + 
    facet_wrap(~gp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hey!, I also tried this code but it gives me this error: `Error: 'plot.data' contains value(s) > grid.max`

Comment: You can set `grid.max=100` in the code and that will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly! However, the plots are not showing the legend at the bottom. How can I get the legends for each group in individual plots?

Comment: The legend isn't showing up because in each plot, you've only got one group.  If you did `ggradar(mydat, grid.max=100)` you would see that you get a legend,

Comment: Hi @DaveArmstrong.  Can I do the same with the function facet_wrap and get all the plots in one?

Comment: @kamalikaray Yes, I updated the answer to show how.